# Point VBA to the second tab of the IE instance

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

The issue is this line:

```
Set TrackID2 = oIE.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
```

Basically, I need VBA to open two instances of a site (in 2 tabs), find the search box and enter & submit a string.

I got the tabs to open, but I can't find a way for VBA to input the right string into the second tab within the instance of IE. Right, now it opens 2 tabs, but inputs both strings into the first tab and searched for it twice there, while the second tab just opens up the address.

How do I edit the code to point VBA to the second tab, instead of the first one, like it does now?

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
Sub TestIE() 

Dim IE As Object 
Dim TrackID As Object 
Dim TrackID2 As Object 
Dim address As String 

address = "https://www.google.com/" 

Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800 
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
oIE.Visible = True 


oIE.Navigate address 
Do Until oIE.readystate = 4: 
    DoEvents: Loop 
    Set TrackID = oIE.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box") 
    TrackID.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("a1") 
    TrackID.form.submit 

    oIE.Navigate2 address, CLng(navOpenInNewTab) 
Do Until oIE.readystate = 4: 
        DoEvents: Loop 
        Set TrackID2 = oIE.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box") 
        TrackID2.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") 
        TrackID.form.submit 

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not perform each search in the same window/tab? Do you need the windows open at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, I do need to open all of them in the same time for comparison purposes. I will probably expand this to have 5-8 tabs at the same time once I figure out the code.

Comment: Is the tab URL different once the form has been submitted? If yes then you could adapt code from here to select the "unsubmitted" tabs: http://vbazone.com/?p=89

Comment: URL does change, once the form is submitted. My VBA/programming experience is very basic, thank you for that suggestion, but that code seems to be over my head. Could you point out the part I can adapt? I appreciate the feedback no matter what. Thank you!

Comment: Just tested, and seems like this method would only retreive the first tab in IE if there are multiple tabs open.  So, it might be easier for you to just create a new instance of IE per page...  There is code out there which allows you to navigate different tabs in the same instance, but it's pretty complex.

Comment: got it thanks. I guess its not end of the world if it opens up in a new instance each time. thanks

Comment: See the answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523271/accessing-ie-tabs-once-created/18417654#18417654)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I decided to do since all other options were beyond my level of expertise...

```
Sub testie2()


Dim oIE As Object
Dim oIE1 As Object
Dim oIE2 As Object
Dim oIE3 As Object
Dim oIE4 As Object
Dim oIE5 As Object
Dim oIE6 As Object
Dim oIE7 As Object
Dim oIE8 As Object
Dim oIE9 As Object

Dim TrackID As Object
Dim TrackID1 As Object
Dim TrackID2 As Object
Dim TrackID3 As Object
Dim TrackID4 As Object
Dim TrackID5 As Object
Dim TrackID6 As Object
Dim TrackID7 As Object
Dim TrackID8 As Object
Dim TrackID9 As Object

'----------------------------0---------------------------------------------
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE.Visible = True


Do Until oIE.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID = oIE.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

TrackID.form.submit

'------------------------------1------------------------------------------

Set oIE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE1.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE1.Visible = True

Do Until oIE1.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID1 = oIE1.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID1.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

TrackID1.form.submit

'------------------------------2-------------------------------------------

Set oIE2 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE2.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE2.Visible = True

Do Until oIE2.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID2 = oIE2.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID2.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A3")

TrackID2.form.submit

'------------------------------3-------------------------------------------

Set oIE3 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE3.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE3.Visible = True

Do Until oIE3.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID3 = oIE3.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID3.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A4")

TrackID3.form.submit

'------------------------------4-------------------------------------------

Set oIE4 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE4.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE4.Visible = True

Do Until oIE4.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID4 = oIE4.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID4.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A5")

TrackID4.form.submit

'------------------------------5-------------------------------------------

Set oIE5 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE5.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE5.Visible = True

Do Until oIE5.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID5 = oIE5.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID5.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A6")

TrackID5.form.submit

'------------------------------6-------------------------------------------

Set oIE6 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE6.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE6.Visible = True

Do Until oIE6.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID6 = oIE6.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID6.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A7")

TrackID6.form.submit

'------------------------------7-------------------------------------------

Set oIE7 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE7.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE7.Visible = True

Do Until oIE7.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID7 = oIE7.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID7.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A8")

TrackID7.form.submit

'------------------------------8-------------------------------------------

Set oIE8 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE8.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE8.Visible = True

Do Until oIE8.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID8 = oIE8.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID8.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A9")

TrackID8.form.submit

'------------------------------9-------------------------------------------

Set oIE9 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE9.Navigate ("https://www.linkedin.com/")
oIE9.Visible = True

Do Until oIE9.ReadyState = 4:
DoEvents: Loop
Set TrackID9 = oIE9.document.getelementbyid("main-search-box")
TrackID9.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A10")

TrackID9.form.submit


End Sub
```

I know its not elegant, but cuts down on manual entry a lot and definitely helps with the job, sure wish could fit all this into tabs though.