# How i can put value on Google search using VBA on ie next tab?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This is the code :

```
Sub FillinternetForm()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "https://google.com"

ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy

DoEvents 'wait until IE is done loading page.

Wend

ie.Document.all("lst-ib").Value = "Fast Sub"

ie.Navigate "https://google.com", CLng(2048)

ie.Document.all("lst-ib").Value = "Fast slow Sub"

End Sub
```

First Tab working well when second open its not fill value guide about this

Comment: Add another `While ie.Busy` Loop after you navigate to google.com the second time

Comment: its not working

Can you check code your self on vba and run its working?
If you get answer so give me code here thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Sub FillinternetForm()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "https://google.com"

ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy

    DoEvents 'wait until IE is done loading page.

Wend

ie.Document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = "Fast Sub"

ie.Navigate "https://google.com", CLng(2048)

While ie.Busy

    DoEvents 'wait until IE is done loading page.

Wend

With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows

    Set ie = .Item(.Count - 1)

End With

While ie.Busy

    DoEvents 'wait until IE is done loading page.

Wend

ie.Document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = "Fast slow Sub"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I did and it worked. But I tested it again and realized that it sometimes enters the second search text in the first tab. Will look into it again as soon as I have time

Comment: Dear i need really urgent this if you do this right now i pleasure you

Comment: Have a look into [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523271/accessing-ie-tabs-once-created)

Comment: Its not my answer i was see but its not work you see my code what is in missing please guide me