# ie.navigate2 document does not return second tabs document

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a vba excel script that opens multiple tabs in IE and populates a textarea.
Something like this:

```
   Sub tab_test()
link1 = "somelink1.com"
link2 = "somelink2.com"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate link1
While IE.busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Set IEdoc = IE.document
    For Each tag In IEdoc.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
        submit_comment = "Some content No1"
        tag.Value = submit_comment
    Next tag

IE.Navigate2 link2, 2048
While IE.busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Set IEdoc2 = IE.document 'Here is the problem. It does not get the new document, but the first tab
    For Each tag In IEdoc2.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
        submit_comment = "Some content No2"
        tag.Value = submit_comment
    Next tag

End Sub
```

Problem is that when I try to set IEdoc2 to the new document, it sets it to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

IE.Document returns a reference to the **active** document. You have not set the document in your 2nd tab to be the active document.

You can probably adapt one of the answers at the following link to your needs.
[Accessing IE Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523271/accessing-ie-tabs-once-created)

Comment: When selecting the second tab using shellwindows I get a "Method Document of object failed"