# VBA excel to control explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

my first post here.:)

I'm more or less new into VBA and I go with my question:
I made a macro on excel to control IE explorer: the goal is open a webpage, then other tab on the same webpage

and make a login in every page.

first step is ok, to open the page and other tabs I successfully use this code:

```
 Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 objIE.Visible = True

    URL = "www.stackoverflow.com" 'only an example

'Navigate to URL
 objIE.Navigate URL
Application.SendKeys ("Username"), True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys ("Password"), True
(...)

'for further tabs

 objIE.Navigate2 strURL(1), 2048  'where strURL(1) is another link to the website

'[I've also tried using Application.SendKeys "{^T}",, True but it doesen't works
Application.SendKeys ("Username"), True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys ("Password"), True
(...)
```

the problem is I can log in in the first tab but not in tab 2, tab 3 etc. I don't understand why
to make the access I use the same code:

```
 Application.SendKeys ("Username"), True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys ("Password"), True
```

it's weired but it works only for the first tab
can someone help me to make it works for any tab of the webpage?

in case, do you think it's possible to make the same with mozilla firefox?

i use excel 14 and explorer 11.

thanks in davance  :)

Comment: It is best to avoid `SendKeys`, set the values of elements instead e.g. `objIE.Document.getElementById("Username").Value = "UserName"`

Comment: I put the line in the code at the Sendkeys position but ...

"error run-time '91' "

I have to declare something before?

Comment: You'll need to inspect the elements on the webpage and find the element that corresponds to the login input, it should be an `<input>` element where `id ="Username"` or similar, it might not be exactly that as it was just an example.

Comment: I got it and "Username" is the input box, but it still doese'nt works.  anyway with Sendkeys it works, but why not in second and furthers tabs? :(

Comment: You'll also need to use something like `objIE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "password"` and then `objIE.Document.getElementById("loginBtn").Click` or whatever the `id` for the login button may be.

Comment: i use the debug and pose some stop just to see if i can fill the input box - login button works good in the first tab, it is not the problem - the matter is about writing data in second tab

Comment: This answer may help, using shell objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523271/accessing-ie-tabs-once-created

Comment: in the last link suggested there are 2 dims i cannot run: Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer; Dim SWs As ShellWindows:  objects unknow.

I've tried in any way, with any example or workaround possibile, but it does not works. :(
The log in is possibile only in the first tab.