# How to close IE browser tabs using VBA

Tags: vba, navbar

I am writing a code to upload excel files to web based tool. Some settings of IE browser are managed organizations system administration hence whenever I open the browser it starts with the tabs from last session means if there were four tabs opened on last session then new IE instance will opens with those four tab. so how can I close all tabs using VBA code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing IE tabs once created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523271/accessing-ie-tabs-once-created)

Comment: close all except one?